# Read multiple barcodes from single image file using Zxing library in java service

Tags: java, spring-boot, zxing, zxing.net

Hi i have created a java service for reading the barcode from image here iam using Zxing library for decoding the text here the challenge is if a file with single barcode it's working fine if there are multiple barcodes it's producing irrelevant result i have given my code below.

**pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

**java service**

```
@GetMapping(value = "OCR/GetBarcodeRead")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get result from Barcode Zxing library")
    public String GetBarcodeRead() throws Exception {

        InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream("images/multiple.jpg");
        BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);

        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);

        return result.getText();

    }
```

**Result is something like this**

```
CODE93
```

**Image with multiple barcodes**

[image]

How should i read and retrieve all the barcodes available in the given image using Zxing library?
Could some one help me to achieve this? thanks in advance

**workaround**

```
@GetMapping(value = "OCR/GetBarcodeRead")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get result from Barcode Zxing library")
    public String GetBarcodeRead() throws Exception {

        InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream("images/multiple.png");
        BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);

        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        MultipleBarcodeReader multipleReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(reader);
        Result[] results = multipleReader.decodeMultiple(bitmap);
        //Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);

        return results.toString();

    }
```

**Working code**

```
@GetMapping(value = "OCR/GetBarcodeRead")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get result from Barcode Zxing library")
    public String GetBarcodeRead() throws Exception {



        InputStream barCodeInputStream = new FileInputStream("images/K71NM.jpg");
        BufferedImage barCodeBufferedImage = ImageIO.read(barCodeInputStream);

        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(barCodeBufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        com.google.zxing.Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        MultipleBarcodeReader bcReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(reader);
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object>();
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Result result : bcReader.decodeMultiple(bitmap, hints)) {
            sb.append(result.getText()).append(" \n");
        }


        return sb.toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       
        String path = "./";

      
        //For Read Single Bar Code Image Info
        System.out.println(readSingleBarcodeImageData(path + "generatedBarCodeImage.jpg"));

        //For Read Multiple Bar Code Image Info
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(readMultipleBarcodeImageData(path + "multipleBarCodeImageDemo.png")));
    }




private static String readSingleBarcodeImageData(String singleImagePath) throws NotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(singleImagePath));
        BinaryBitmap bb = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(img)));
        MultipleBarcodeReader mbReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(new MultiFormatReader());
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<>();
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        /*List<BarcodeInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();//if have any custom data then convert to dto like this
        for (Result result : mbReader.decodeMultiple(bb, hints)) {
            list.add(new BarcodeInfo(result.getText(), result.getBarcodeFormat().name()));
        }
        return list;*/
        Result[] currentBarCodeResult = mbReader.decodeMultiple(bb, hints);
        return currentBarCodeResult[0].getText();
    }

    private static Result[] readMultipleBarcodeImageData(String multipleImagePath /* if have multiple barcode in an image then*/) throws NotFoundException, IOException {//
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(multipleImagePath));
        BinaryBitmap bb = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(img)));
        MultipleBarcodeReader mbReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(new MultiFormatReader());
        Hashtable<DecodeHintType, Object> hints = new Hashtable<>();
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        /*List<BarcodeInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();//if have any custom data then convert to dto like this
        for (Result result : mbReader.decodeMultiple(bb, hints)) {
            list.add(new BarcodeInfo(result.getText(), result.getBarcodeFormat().name()));
        }
        return list;*/
        Result[] currentBarCodeResult = mbReader.decodeMultiple(bb, hints);//every result represent a bar code
        return currentBarCodeResult;
    }
```

**For more Details Follow This Example: [Single and multiple barcode data read example](https://github.com/MdGolam-Kibria/JavaBrainStore/blob/master/src/main/java/com/CrackCode/BarCodeQrCodeReadWrite/BarCode/BarCodeExample.java) **

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your reader into a `GenericMultipleBarcodeReader` and use `decodeMultiple` that returns an array of results:

```
MultipleBarcodeReader multipleReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(reader);
Result[] results = multipleReader.decodeMultiple(bitmap);
```

[Reference](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/multi/GenericMultipleBarcodeReader.html)

Comment: I have tried not working i have given the code, Kindly check

Comment: Can you clarify what result you are getting?

Comment: I am getting result like this **[Lcom.google.zxing.Result;@776b694c**

Comment: That's because you are calling toString directly on the array. You have to iterate through it and get the values individually. I suggest you run it in debug mode and use a breakpoint to get more familiar with the structure there.

Comment: It's working now, i have given the working code above, Thank a lot

Comment: Hi @Alex  - Created another topic related to library apache camel attached link for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60389632/unable-to-read-a-barcode-using-apache-camel